# Get the stored procedure schema

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, codedom

I'm trying to write a framework to generate entities from an existing database.

I've already implemented all the code to generate the entities from the tables and it works well.
Now I'm looking for a solution to retrieve all the information I need to generate a stored procedure entity.

This is the code I use to get the stored procedure parameters

```
public static List<StoredProcedureParameter> GetStoredProceduresParameters(SqlConnection connection, string storedProcedureName, bool closeConnection = true)
{
   var query = @"select Parameter_Name, Data_Type, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
                 from information_schema.parameters
                 where specific_name = @StoredProcedureName";

   var storedProcedures = new List<string>();

   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("StoredProcedureName", storedProcedureName));

   DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

   using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
   {
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
   }

   if (closeConnection)
   {
      connection.Close();
   }

   return DataTableMapper.ReadDataTableList<StoredProcedureParameter>(dataTable);
}
```

Now I have to retrieve the result set schema, but I can't find the right way to accomplish this task. Any suggestions?

**NOTE**: all the stored procedures will **always** return just one possible schema, so any one stored procedure will always correspond to exactly one entity.

Comment: There's no view or anything to find out what the stored procedure returns - you'll either need to **execute** it and see what you get back, or you'll need to grab and parse it's source code

Answer (score 1):

Hi SimoneL: There are frameworks to do just that for you, NHibernate or EF (Entity Framework) from Microsoft, do they not answer all your needs?

EF getting Started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ee712907#getstarted

Comment: Thanks yonks, I know there is plenty of Framework with the same aim, but I'm developing a custom library to improve my skills and my knowledge.

Anyway I'll try to look into these Frameworks, maybe I can understand how they works!

Comment: One way is to look at what EF does as you can open the .Designer.cs file. I looked at one of my EF codes, it seems it maps to the base Object (ObjectContext) and execs a function. which makes sense as you dont want an object for each StoredProc you have. return base.ExecuteFunction("AuditLogMessageEnd"...) Where AuditLogMessageEnd is the name of my SP.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817847/schema-from-stored-procedure/29678188#29678188):

You don't want to call the SP when you want to know the schema, as you may affect data.